# potential data loss occur due to inserting data from input column “Inac” with data type “DT_I8” to external column “Inact” with data type “DT_I4”

Tags: ssis, ssms

Getting a warning saying potential data loss may occur due to inserting data from input column "Inact" with data type "DT_I8" to external column "Inact" with data type "DT_I4".

When I checked the mapping "The column Inact has Available Input column as BOOLEAN [DT_BOOL] and Available Output column as signed-byte unsigned integer [DT_UT1]. How can I fix it?

Is that also the reason why my data is not shown when ETL occurs and I have to rerun the package manually?

Comment: What are your source and destination types? OLEDB? Excel? Your question does not have enough information.

Comment: I am new to this integration, so probably don't know waht all information should be provided. I am using OLEDB

Comment: Check your source columns, normally database columns. What is the database dataype of "Inact" column?